# Why is addEventListener not attaching to the Soundcloud embedded player widget?

Tags: javascript, widget, event-listener

I am trying to addEventListener('click') to the entire div id="audioPlayer" which contains an iframe that embeds a Soundcloud playlist in there. Everything is working almost perfectly except my console does not show the log "I am clicked".

Can someone point me in the right direction of why nothing is showing up in the console when I click the entire div?

There are no errors in the console, I just can't get the "I am clicked" to show up whenever I click anywhere within the div and I don't understand what I am doing wrong when it should be pretty straightforward.

```
<body>
<!-- embedded soundcloud playlist -->
    <div id="audioPlayer">
        <iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay"
            src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?    url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/1581476539&color=FFD700&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&visual=true">
        </iframe>
   <div>

   <script src="visual.js">
        const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');

        audioPlayer.addEventListener('click', function(e){
              console.log('I am clicked');
        })
    </script>
</body>
```